# How create associations between two models if one has two ID's from another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to Rails and still learning the associations and I'm stuck with a model relationship.
How should I associate these two models?

```
Model Team 
id => 1, name => Toronto
id => 2, name => Montreal
id => 3, name => Detroit

Model Game
id => 1, hometeam_id => 1, awayteam_id => 2
id => 2, hometeam_id => 3, awayteam_id => 2

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  ???
end

class Game< ActiveRecord::Base
  ???
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :games
end

class Game< ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :hometeam, class_name: "Team", foreign_key: :hometeam_id
 belongs_to :awayteam, class_name: "Team", foreign_key: :awayteam_id
end
```

Comment: I have Soccer and Cricket games should i design two Team and Game models or strore all in one? In future planned Model Schedule with game_id (soccer or cricket)

Comment: @user3627081 That wont be need i guess so.You can just create `name` attribute in `games` table and save the names under it,in your case `soccer` and `cricket` would be the names.

Comment: If i want to create models for statistics i need two different models soccet_stats and cricket_stats wright?

Comment: @user3627081 Yes i guess so.Go on with your thought.If you are stuck again come back with the problem.We are here to help :)

Comment: @Pavan pls add code to retrieve games for a team. It will be good reference for others who stumble upon this question. thanks.